# Rails group_by total amount

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, group-by

I'm using Rails & MySql, At the moment, my data shows like this in a view:

```
Customer A, 5
Customer B, 3
Customer C, 2
Customer A, 2
Customer B, 4
```

I want it to show like this:

```
Customer A, 7
Customer B, 7
Customer C, 2
```

Currently my .html.erb view looks like this:

```
<% @licenses.each do |l| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= l.customer.companyname %></td>
    <td><%= l.customer.licensecontact %></td>
    <td><%= l.amount %></td>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

I'm pretty sure i need to add something after `@licenses.each` I'm just not sure what?

Comment: Hi Carla, you have to update your query. i.e. from where you are fetching the `@licenses` check my Edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a very little information provided by you, i think You have to use Group BY

```
SELECT customer, SUM(quantity) AS quantity FROM orders GROUP BY customer
```

Using Rails 3

```
Order.select("customer, SUM(quantity) AS quantity").group("customer")
```

Using Rails 2 #This will work in Rails 3 as well

```
Order.find(:all, :select => "customer, SUM(quantity) AS quantity", :group => "customer")
```

EDITED

You have to fetcth the record in something like following way

```
@licenses = License.find_by_sql("SELECT c.companyname, c.licensecontact, SUM(l.amount) 
                                  FROM licenses l 
                                  LEFT JOIN customers c ON c.id=l.customer_id
                                  GROUP BY c.companyname, c.licensecontact")
```

Change you view to following

```
<% @licenses.each do |l| %>
<tr>
    <td><%= l.companyname %></td>
    <td><%= l.licensecontact %></td>
    <td><%= l.amount %></td>
    </td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok I put that in my controller and got this error `Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'companyname' in 'field list': SELECT companyname, licensecontact, SUM(amount) AS amount FROM 'licenses'  GROUP BY companyname, licensecontact`

Comment: Sorry i forgot the association, you have to use `LEFT JOIN`, check again above `find_by_sql` query

Comment: it seems to accept that, but i then get an error in my view : `undefined method 'companyname' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Go to app/models and copy here content of files in that dir.

Comment: Change your view as above i.e. remove `.customer`

Comment: removed `.customer` now i get this : `missing attribute: amount`

Comment: In your query change `SUM(l.amount)` to `SUM(l.amount) AS amount`